# Wrong URL opened after changing the browser of IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to open IPython (version `3.0.0`) Notebook with Safari, which is not my default browser, so I made a modification:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari %s'
```

in this file:

```
.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py
```

Safari does open successfully. However, the only problem is that the URL opened by safari is (`xujc` is my user name):

```
file:///Users/xujc/http:/localhost:8888/tree
```

instead of

```
http:/localhost:8888/tree
```

How can I remove `file:///Users/xujc/` and make it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the line below to `ipython_config.py` works for me:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'safari'
```

Comment: Your hint solved my problem. I just need to modify  `c.NotebookApp.browser` to `u'safari'` as you suggested (still in `.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py`).

Comment: ps: During the past few days, I can't accept the answer or add a comment due to the fact that many websites including Google Scholar are blocked by the Chinese government (and thus some javescripts used by stackoverflow can not be loaded). I find a way to unblock just now.